# Start-Process variable

Tags: powershell

I have that code:

```bsh
$Switch = Read-Host "`n`rPlease choose account: `n`r
1. Account 1. `n`r
2. Account 2. `n`r

Please enter the number of the option you would like"

switch ($Switch) {
1 {
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential x,(‘x’ | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString “x” -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“x”, $password)
}
2 {
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential x,(‘x’ | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString “x” -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“x”, $password)
}
}

#$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential x,(‘x’ | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

$args = "F:\Teams\Files\GISAppTeams.ps1"

Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $Credentials -ArgumentList ("-file $args")
```

How can I pass the variable `$credential` to the `Start-Process` cmdlet so it will be available in the new script instance?

Comment: Can you add more details about the `GISAppTeams.ps1` script and what you're trying to accomplish? Why would you need an explicit credential object if you launch the script with the desired credentials already?

Comment: In GISAppTeams.ps1 I use credential from $credential to connect to the Microsoft cloud.

Comment: So start-proccess allows me to run GISAppTeams.ps1 and another user and I need to push credentials there.

Comment: Can you try and confirm using the "default" block in the switch if it is working or not? And try adding default credentials in the default block

Comment: @Aditya What do You mean?

Comment: Are you referencing the intended `$Credential(s)` variable?  Why do you have 2 of them?

Comment: @Budrys I was suggesting to add a default in the switch conditioning and try. I am not sure of it.

Comment: IS one of the parameters for GISAppTeams.ps1 Credential?

Comment: @ArcSet - Yes, I need to use $credential in GISAppTeams.ps1

Comment: Does GISAppTeams.ps1 start with `Function GISAppTeams` or `Params(`

Comment: @ArcSet - Here is what I have in GISAppTeams:Import-Module "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Skype for Business Online\\Modules\\SkypeOnlineConnector\\SkypeOnlineConnector.psd1"



        $session = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $credential -OverrideAdminDomain qg1.onmicrosoft.com
        Import-PSSession $session
        Enable-CsOnlineSessionForReconnection

        Connect-MsolService -Credential $Credential

Comment: Anybody has any idea?